# "Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node." on component rerender

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router-dom, webpack-dev-server

I have found an issue that makes me unable to use `react-router-dom` links that's stated in the title.
Minimal reproduction model:

// index.js

```
import React from "react";
import client from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
const root = client.createRoot(rootElement);

root.render(
        <App></App>
)
```

// App.js

```
import React, {Component} from "react";
import {BrowserRouter as Router} from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "./Navbar";

export default class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {  };
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {

        setTimeout(() => {
            this.setState({authorised: true});
        }, 5000);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Navbar authorised={this.state.authorised}/>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}
```

// Navbar.js

```
import React from 'react'
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";

export default function Navbar(props) {
    if(!props.authorised) return (
        <>
            <Link to="/">
                Home
            </Link>
            <Link to="/login">
                Login
            </Link>
            <Link to="/register">
                Register
            </Link>
        </>
    )
    return(
        <>
            <Link to="/">
                Home
            </Link>
            <Link to="/dashboard">
                Dashboard
            </Link>
            <Link to="/search">
                Search
            </Link>
        </> 
    )
}
```

Issue is this, timeout triggers changing a state, state causes the component to be rerendered, Navbar.js causes website to crash with error of

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
```

While pointing on the Link  component.
Am I doing something wrong here? Version of RRD is v6.

edit:

Adding package.json contents on request:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node .",
    "test": "jest --watchAll",
    "build": "webpack --mode production",
    "dev_frontend": "webpack-dev-server --mode development --open --hot",
    "dev_backend": "nodemon .",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others \"npm run dev_backend\" \"npm run dev_frontend\""
},
"dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bcrypt": "^5.0.1",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.0",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "express-mysql-session": "^2.1.8",
    "express-session": "^1.17.2",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "jest": "^28.0.3",
    "joi": "^17.6.0",
    "mysql2": "^2.3.3",
    "pug": "^3.0.2",
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-router": "^6.3.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
    "supertest": "^6.2.3",
    "swagger-jsdoc": "^6.2.1",
    "swagger-ui-express": "^4.3.0",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "yup": "^0.32.11"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.10",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.17.10",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.7",
    "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
    "concurrently": "^7.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^5.5.0",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.16",
    "webpack": "^5.72.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^4.9.0"
}
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require("path");
const HTMLWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");


module.exports = {
    entry: path.join(__dirname, "views", "index.js"),
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, "views"),
        filename: 'bundle.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new HTMLWebpackPlugin({
            template: path.join(__dirname, "views", "index.html")
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /.js$/,
                exclude: /(node_modules)|(tools)|(routes)|(public)/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react']
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        hot: true
    },
    target: "web"
}
```

Comment: I'm unable to reproduce this issue/error in this running [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/failed-to-execute-removechild-on-node-the-node-to-be-removed-is-not-a-chil-p5kbvi). Can you share your `package.json` file contents, and check the installed versions of `react` and `react-router-dom`? From the project directory run `npm list react react-router-dom`.

Comment: @DrewReese I already updated the post. I also added my webpack configuration and the scripts I am using. Build version apparently also throws the same error.